# Why my HB100's amplifying circuit can't generate more than a signal of 200 Hz?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog

I want to amplify the HB100's IF signal with the circuit shown below, but when I test my circuit I can't read more than 200 Hz, maximum 300 Hz. The circuit works with the OPA2365 integrated circuit at 5V. The first stage has a bandwith between 0.01 Hz and 7.23 kHz:

$$f_{inf1} = \frac{1}{2 \pi R6 C3} = 0.01 Hz$$
$$f_{sup1} = \frac{1}{2 \pi R5 C4} = 7.23 kHz$$

With a similar approach, the second stage has a bandwidth between 0.02 and 8.8 kHz. Are these calculations correct? What's wrong in the circuit?

[image]

Comment: Have you simulated the circuit, and does it work in simulation?

Answer (score 1):

That first stage has a feedback time constant (using 1Meg ohm and 2.2 nano Farads, or 2200 picoFarads) of 1e+6 * 2.2e-9 == 2.2e-3, or 2.2 milliSeconds.

The 3dB point, in radians, is 1/0.0022 == 420 radians per second.

To convert to cycles-per-second (aka Hertzz), divide 420 by 2*pi, and you learn the 3dB point, which is also the 45-degree-phaseshift point, is about 70 cycles-per-second.

You have a fine approach, but two feedback timeconstants that are 100X too low.

Your circuit is

1) input DC blocking

2) high-pass-filter in bottom-gain-set impedance for gain-stage#1

3) low-pass-filter in top impedance of gain-set ratio for gain-stage#1, which should be 22pF, not 2200pF (not 2.2nanoFarad)

4) repeat of (2)

5) repeat of (3)

By the way, your opamps will NOT block high frequencies, because their high-frequency gain approaches ZERO and the Zout of the opamps SOARS, which allows the high-frequency energy to flow AROUND the opamp thru those 2.2nanoFarad capacitors.

Solution? add a PASSIVE RC lowpass filter before the opamps.

Answer (score 0):

That is also what I calculate. Each opamp has a lowpass filter of 2.2nF parallel with 1M which produces -3dB at 73Hz with a 6dB per octave slope.
Your schematic is the same as in the HB100 applications note except they wrongly call the 1M resistors as 1m and use a lousy old LM324 quad opamp.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the feedback network of your pre-amp as,

[image]

The forward transfer function of your amplifier is,

$$ H(s) = 1 + \frac{Z_F}{Z_A} $$

The mid-band gain of your amplifier is,

$$ A_V = 1 + \frac{R_6}{R_5} = 101 \text{ V/V} \simeq 40 \text{ dB}$$

Note when the impedance of \$C_4\$ approaches that of \$R_6\$ the mid-band gain begins to decline.

A quick spice simulation confirms this:
[image]

The resulting spice simulation results are shown below.
[image]

**Solution:** Reduce \$C_4\$ to achieve desired pass-band bandwidth.